# Why do I get a SettingWithCopyWarning a value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice?

Tags: pandas

when running the following code :

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1,2,3],"B": [2,4,8]})
df2 = df[df["A"] < 3]
df2["C"] = 100
```

I get the following warning :

> SettingWithCopyWarning:  A value
>   is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame. Try using
>   .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead See the caveats in the
>   documentation:
>   http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy

but this is exactly the behavior I want ( the real table is very big and I don't want to make copies of it), why do I get a warning ? why is it risky ?

```
df

   A  B
0  1  2
1  2  4
2  3  8

df2

   A  B    C
0  1  2  100
1  2  4  100
```

Comment: Because `df2` is a copy of a slice of `df`. Try: `df2 = df[df["A"] < 3].copy()`

Comment: it is a very big DataFrame I don't want to make copeis of it, why is it risky to work with view ?

Comment: you are only copying the slice, but use `loc` if you don't want to copy it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Why does this happen?**

Because `df2` is a copy of a slice of `df`.

**Why is it risky?**

This is a message that tells you that `df2` and `df` are different things. This was introduced because it wasn't always obvious that they were.

Take the example code from the docs:

```
def do_something(df):
   foo = df[['bar', 'baz']]  # Is foo a view? A copy? Nobody knows!
   # ... many lines here ...
   foo['quux'] = value       # We don't know whether this will modify df or not!
   return foo
```

**How do I solve it?**

Either by explicitly copying the slice:

```
df2 = df[df['A'] < 3].copy()
df2['C'] = 100
```

or by using `loc`:

```
df.loc[df['A'] < 3, 'C'] = 100
```