# How to fetch more information from imdb and save it in pandas data frame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, imdb, imdbpy

I am learning pandas and python,

I want to fetch more information about movies from IMDB library and save it in an addition column in my already existing data frame.

For example:     `df['titleId']`  has movie IDS in my data frame *(total almost 50-60)*

(with the help of ImdbPy library), I want to create new column  `df['movie_name']` in same data frame to store movie names for that particular movie ID `df['titleId']`

I managed to do it with one value (not in data frame) but not able to handle it in dataframe. Please help.

```
Code to get movie name is as under:

#### YEAR OF THE MOVE

# importing the module
import imdb

# creating instance of IMDb
ia = imdb.IMDb()

# getting the movie with id
search = ia.get_movie("2082197")

# getting movie year
year = search['year']

# printing movie name and year
print(search['title'] + " : " + str(year))
```

Comment: Are you looking for [`Series.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html) -> `df['movie_name'] = df['titleID'].apply(lambda x: ia.get_movie(x)['title'])`? [How can I use the apply() function for a single column?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34962104/15497888)

Comment: @HenryEcker it worked ... thanks a lot for help. may you rise and shine :)

Comment: What warning are you getting?

Comment: @HenryEcker  ... it worked fine but its giving a warning as well... (I know one should ignore them, but as a learner i want to know about it ...) i will really appriciate if you explain this wanring

Comment: @HenryEcker  A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy

Comment: Okay so somewhere you've unsafely subset your DataFrame. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53496996/15497888) explains somewhat about what's happening. [also here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54914752/15497888)

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you are looking for [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html).

As a toy example, if you have a dataframe A with columns (id, name) and another dataframe B with columns (id, year), you can do `A.merge(B, how="left")` to get a dataframe C with columns (id, name, year). Note that if B is much smaller than A (i.e., if there are ids in A that are not in B), then you can get nan values in C - you can explore other type of joins for this.